# How can I create a local account on a machine is already signed onto a microsoft account?

Tags: windows-10, login, active-directory

I have a  work laptop that's using active directory for authentication, and I typically login with a work microsoft account. I've created a local admin user on the laptop using instructions similar to those on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923/windows-10-create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account).

Windows asks me for a username and password during the process, and the user is created. However, no folder was created under `C:\Users`. The bigger issue is that I'm unable to actually login with this account. The login screen only asks for the PIN, which wasn't even part of the user creation process!

I tried clicking on forget pin, but it always says "The user name or pin is incorrect. Try again". Windows doesn't seem to recognize `username`, `HOSTNAME\username`, `.\username` as valid local account user names.

User list (the user i've created has been blacked out):
[image: user list]

Is it possible to create/use local accounts on a machine that has logged in with a microsoft account ?

Comment: You can view/edit local accounts by running the `lusrmgr.msc` snap in. Consider including that as a screen shot in your post.

Comment: Do you mean a personal Microsoft account (like an @outlook.com), or an Azure AD account, or a traditional Active Directory account?

Comment: It's a work laptop, I'm connected to my company's Azure AD

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, added a screenshot

Comment: *no folder was created under C:\Users*... This won't happen until you log in with the account at least once.